# Can we edit and update tableau data using JavaScript API

Tags: javascript

I want to know can we edit data and update data using Tableau JavaScript API. I tried but didn’t get any function to do this work, for now I  can only change view ,download data, filter data, customized  view. If edit data can be done using JavaScript API ,please share any tutorial on this.

Answer (score 0):

```
try like this:-

<title>getData() Basic Example</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/tableau-2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var viz, sheet, table;

            function initViz() {
        var containerDiv = document.getElementById("vizContainer"),
                    url = "http://public.tableau.com/views/RegionalSampleWorkbook/Storms",
                    options = {
                        hideTabs: true,
                        hideToolbar: true,
                        onFirstInteractive: function () {
                            document.getElementById('getData').disabled = false; // Enable our button
                        }
                    };
                viz = new tableau.Viz(containerDiv, url, options);
            }

<body onload="initViz();">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>getData() Basic Example</h1>
            <p>Click the "Get Data" button to get underlying data for the viz.</p>
            <button id="getData" onclick="getUnderlyingData()" class="btn" disabled>Get Data</button>
        </div>
        <div id="vizContainer" style="width:600px; height:600px;"></div>
        <div id="dataTarget"></div>
    </body>
```

Comment: HI Anand,Thanks, but i need to edit data in server using Tableue Javascript API